# Gnuplot with latex and bash

Tags: eps, gnuplot, epslatex

I have created a bash script that accesses and plots data using gnuplot. For this i have had to use the $ variable bash symbol. How can I plot an eps file where i can had a hat or tilde with special characters in the xlabels and ylabels?

```
$\hat{x}/ \lambda_D$
```

my current terminal is

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica, 18'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, don't you have to escape the dollar sign somehow? It is really hard for me to follow, as dollar signs are used in all three languages, everytime with a different meaning. Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are looking for the `epslatex` terminal.
So begin your Gnuplot script with

```
set terminal epslatex
set output 'output.tex'
```

then you can use latex notation like

```
set xlabel '$\hat{x}/ \lambda_D$'
```

this should output a `.eps` file with the plot and and the `.tex` file where the plot is embedded and the labels are set. You can use it with `\input{output}` in your LaTeX file.

I am not sure how your bash script works, possibly you have to escape the `$`, i.e. `\$`.